# The searchbar of my django website isnt working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

This is the code in my base site(i.e base.html) for search bar:

```
       <form  method="get" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">

        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="search_box" type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this site" style="width:550%">

            <span class="input-group-btn">

                   <button type="submit" id="s1" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>

            </span>
        </div>
```

url of the searchbar view(present in "urls.py" of "myapp":

`url(r'^search/?$', views.search)`

view of the searchbar:
def search(request):

```
query= request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    queryset_list= queryset_list.filter(title__icontain=query)
```

I dont know why it's not working. im able to see search item in web browser url bar. but it's not showing any results in the webpage.

Comment: well you never return a HTTP response (given you showed *all* the data). But perhaps it is better to create a MWE, since now you left out that much that it is hard to tell. Also please post a traceback.

Comment: can you explain a lil bit what you have said